# How to work around MVC4's breaking change in how it renders bools in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

We recently upgraded an existing .NET 4 MVC 3 project to .NET 4.5 and MVC 4.

Where we had this sort of thing in a view:

```
@Model.MyBool
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="@Model.MyBool" />
```

that used to render as:

```
True
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="True" />
```

or:

```
False
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="False" />
```

But now it renders as:

```
True
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="value" />
```

or:

```
False
<input type="hidden" name="foo" />
```

That is, where a boolean property is rendered in the view as the value of a hidden input's value attribute, it doesn't render as `True` or `False` (as it does elsewhere), but rather renders as `value`, or misses the attribute altogether.

Two questions:

1. WTF?
2. Is there a nice easy way I can fix the multitude of places that this has broken my application? It's a big application and I don't fancy trawling through every single view to try to identify everywhere I put a bool into an input field.

Answer (score 3):

> WTF?

[Razor 2 conditional attributes](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/conditional-attributes-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp.net-mvc-4)

> Is there a nice easy way I can fix the multitude of places that this has broken my application?

None I can think of (that's why you should have used `@Html.Hidden("foo", Model.MyBool)`). My best guess would be using something like Resharper's Structured Replace.

Comment: Shame. I tended not to use `Html.Hidden(...)` because I didn't want an `id` on my hiddens (there's lots of instances of the same Partial View on the same page). And the way I wrote it made for more readable code, imho. Well, that's my excuse anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Because I had many instances of the same partial view, that would've given me many elements with the same `id`, which isn't nice.

Comment: @teedyay that means they'd have same name too (which isn't nice too). And that means your view is structured strangely.

Comment: Is there a way to return to Razor 1? I tried changing the web.config in the Views folder, with no joy:
`<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="[snipped so it fits in this comment], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="[...], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="[...], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />`

(The only change is that they were Version=2.0.0.0 before.)

Answer (score 2):

looks like this is working:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="@Model.MyBool.ToString()" />
```

Comment: Yes, that is the way to fix one instance. I was hoping there would be a way to change the behaviour back for the whole site so I didn't have to hunt through every view to find everywhere I needed to change this. I didn't find one, unfortunately.